# A category with finite limits which is not regular well powered.

Tags: category-theory

I am looking for a locally small category with finite limits that is not regular well powered.

Do you know any?

Comment: "Regular well powered" means every object has a small set of regular subobjects?

Comment: Yes. Precisely that.

Comment: You could use https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93853/abelian-category-which-is-not-well-powered but maybe there’s a simpler example